# React update state when click

Tags: reactjs, api, loops, react-hooks, state

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Container, Row } from "react-bootstrap";
import ListCategories from "./ListCategories";
import Hasil from "./Hasil";
import DaftarProduk from "./DaftarProduk";
import axios from "axios";
import keranjang from "../utils/keranjang";
import BASE_URL from "../utils/constata";

const Main = () => {
  const [dataProduct, setDataProduct] = useState([]);
  const [dataCategories, setDataCategories] = useState([]);
  const [categoriesId, setCategoriesId] = useState(1);
  const [listPesanan, setListPesanan] = useState([]);

  const handleListCategories = (id) => {
    setCategoriesId(id);
  };

  const handleProdukClick = async (produk) => {
    keranjang(produk);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const getProducts = async () => {
      let responseJson = [];
      try {
        responseJson = await axios.get(
          BASE_URL + "products?category.id=" + categoriesId
        );
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("Ada yang " + error);
      } finally {
        setDataProduct(responseJson.data);
      }
    };

    const getCategories = async () => {
      let responseJson = [];
      try {
        responseJson = await axios.get(BASE_URL + "categories");
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("Ada yang " + error);
      } finally {
        setDataCategories(responseJson.data);
      }
    };

    const getPesanans = async () => {
      let responseJson = [];
      try {
        responseJson = await axios.get(BASE_URL + "keranjangs");
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("Ada yang " + error);
      } finally {
        setListPesanan(responseJson.data);
      }
    };

    getProducts();
    getCategories();
    getPesanans();
  }, [categoriesId]);

  return (
    <Container className="mt-3">
      <Row>
        {dataCategories && (
          <ListCategories
            categories={dataCategories}
            handleClick={handleListCategories}
            categoriesActive={categoriesId}
          ></ListCategories>
        )}
        {dataProduct && (
          <DaftarProduk
            produk={dataProduct}
            handleClick={handleProdukClick}
          ></DaftarProduk>
        )}
        <Hasil pesanan={listPesanan}></Hasil>
      </Row>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default Main;
```

---

How to update `listPesanan`, when `handleProdukClick` was click?

if me put `listPesanan` inside

```
useEffect(() => {
    const getProducts = async () => {
      let responseJson = [];
      try {
        responseJson = await axios.get(
          BASE_URL + "products?category.id=" + categoriesId
        );
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("Ada yang " + error);
      } finally {
        setDataProduct(responseJson.data);
      }
    };

    const getCategories = async () => {
      let responseJson = [];
      try {
        responseJson = await axios.get(BASE_URL + "categories");
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("Ada yang " + error);
      } finally {
        setDataCategories(responseJson.data);
      }
    };

    const getPesanans = async () => {
      let responseJson = [];
      try {
        responseJson = await axios.get(BASE_URL + "keranjangs");
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("Ada yang " + error);
      } finally {
        setListPesanan(responseJson.data);
      }
    };

    getProducts();
    getCategories();
    getPesanans();
  }, [categoriesId, listPesanan]);
```

that's causes looping to send request to server[image]

my full code in [here](https://github.com/kkzio/kasir-app)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your second 'solution' will cause looping, because you have `listPesanan` in you dependency array (The second parameter to the useEffect function), so whenever `listPesanan` changes, the useEffect is run again. And in fact, you are updating the value of `listPesanan` in the useEffect, which causes the useEffect to get triggered again, which causes you to update the value of listPesanan, and so on.

If I understand your question/code, a simple solution would just be to declare the `getPesanans` function **outside** of the `useEffect` hook, and then have your `DaftarProduk` onClick call that function. Then, remove listPesanan from the dependency array of `useEffect`. Your code would look like this:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Container, Row } from "react-bootstrap";
import ListCategories from "./ListCategories";
import Hasil from "./Hasil";
import DaftarProduk from "./DaftarProduk";
import axios from "axios";
import keranjang from "../utils/keranjang";
import BASE_URL from "../utils/constata";

const Main = () => {
  const [dataProduct, setDataProduct] = useState([]);
  const [dataCategories, setDataCategories] = useState([]);
  const [categoriesId, setCategoriesId] = useState(1);
  const [listPesanan, setListPesanan] = useState([]);

  **const getPesanans = async () => {
    let responseJson = [];
    try {
      responseJson = await axios.get(BASE_URL + "keranjangs");
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Ada yang " + error);
    } finally {
      setListPesanan(responseJson.data);
    }
  };**


  const handleListCategories = (id) => {
    setCategoriesId(id);
  };

  const handleProdukClick = async (produk) => {
    keranjang(produk);
    **await getPesanans();**
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const getProducts = async () => {
      let responseJson = [];
      try {
        responseJson = await axios.get(
          BASE_URL + "products?category.id=" + categoriesId
        );
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("Ada yang " + error);
      } finally {
        setDataProduct(responseJson.data);
      }
    };

    const getCategories = async () => {
      let responseJson = [];
      try {
        responseJson = await axios.get(BASE_URL + "categories");
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("Ada yang " + error);
      } finally {
        setDataCategories(responseJson.data);
      }
    };


    getProducts();
    getCategories();
    getPesanans();
  }, [categoriesId]);

  return (
    <Container className="mt-3">
      <Row>
        {dataCategories && (
          <ListCategories
            categories={dataCategories}
            handleClick={handleListCategories}
            categoriesActive={categoriesId}
          ></ListCategories>
        )}
        {dataProduct && (
          <DaftarProduk
            produk={dataProduct}
            handleClick={handleProdukClick}
          ></DaftarProduk>
        )}
        <Hasil pesanan={listPesanan}></Hasil>
      </Row>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default Main;
```

Comment: Before, I tried the code like you, but it updates just when I refresh the page. Not when you click the button.

Answer (score 0):

**problem**

First `handleProdukClick` triggers another effect, `keranjang`.

```js
const handleProdukClick = async (produk) => { // ⚠️ async misuse
  keranjang(produk); // ⚠️ effect
  // ✏️ update listPesanan here ...
};
```

**code review**

Your [linked source code](https://github.com/kkzio/kasir-app/blob/deaadaa53db18172588d09743f1a105b956aeb03/src/utils/keranjang.js#L5-L42) shows this implementation for `keranjang`. This code misunderstands how to effectively apply `async` and `await`. Let's fix that first.

- ⚠️ `await..then` anti-pattern doesn't assign result to variable
- ⚠️ 38-LOC function with mixed concerns
- ⚠️ Errors are swallowed so caller cannot respond to them

```js
const keranjang = async (produk) => {
  let pesanan = {
    jumlah: 1,
    total_harga: produk.harga,
    product: produk,
  };

  const popUpPesanan = () => // ⚠️ nested function, no arguments
    swal({
      title: "Berhasil",
      text: "Masuk Keranjang " + produk.nama,
      icon: "success",
      button: "Oke",
    });

  await axios // ⚠️ no return
    .get(BASE_URL + "keranjangs?product.id=" + produk.id)
    .then(async (res) => {
      if (res.data.length === 0) {
        await axios // ⚠️ no return
          .post(BASE_URL + "keranjangs", pesanan)
          .then(() => popUpPesanan())
          .catch((error) => console.log(error)); // ⚠️ swallow error
      } else {
        pesanan = { // ⚠️ variable reassignment
          jumlah: res.data[0].jumlah + 1,
          total_harga: res.data[0].total_harga + produk.harga,
          product: produk,
        };

        await axios // ⚠️ no return
          .put(BASE_URL + "keranjangs/" + res.data[0].id, pesanan)
          .then(() => popUpPesanan())
          .catch((error) => console.log(error)); // ⚠️ swallow error
      }
    })
    .catch((error) => console.log(error)); // ⚠️ swallow error
};
```

First write `keranjang` from a high-level.

- ✅ Reusable `get`, `add`, and `increase` functions decouple separate concerns
- ✅ Return `Promise` so `handleProduckClick` can know when it is complete
- ✅ Pass arguments to functions instead of reassigning variables
- ✅ Do not swallow error messages with `.catch`

```js
const keranjang = async (produk) => {
  const pesanan = await get(produk.id)
  if (pesanan.length === 0)
    return add(produk).then(() => popUpPesanan(produk))
  else
    return increase(pesanan[0], produk).then(() => popUpPesanan(produk))
}
```

- ✅ Implement `get`, `add`, `increase`
- ✅ Each function returns a `Promise`

```js
const get = (id) =>
  axios.get(`${BASE_URL}keranjangs?product.id=${id}`).then(res => res.data)

const add = (produk) =>
  axios.post(`${BASE_URL}keranjangs`, {
    jumlah: 1,
    total_harga: produk.harga,
    product: produk,
  })

const increase = (pesanan, produk) =>
  axios.put(`${BASE_URL}keranjangs/${pesanan.id}`, {
    jumlah: pesanan.jumlah + 1,
    total_harga: pesanan.total_harga + produk.harga,
    product: produk,
  })
```

- `popUpPesanan` accepts a `produk` argument

```js
const popUpPesanan = (produk) =>
  swal({
    title: "Berhasil",
    text: "Masuk Keranjang " + produk.nama,
    icon: "success",
    button: "Oke",
  })
```

**fix #1**

With all of that fixed, `handleProdukClick` can appropriately respond to the `keranjang` call.

```js
const handleProdukClick = async (produk) => {
  try {
    await keranjang(produk) // ✅ await
    setListPesanan(await getPesanans())// ✅ await and set
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err) // ✅ caller handles error
  }
};
```

You don't need `async` and `await` for this. It's easier to write

```js
const handleProdukClick = (produk) => {
  keranjang(produk).then(setListPesanan).catch(console.error)
}
```

**fix #2**

Now you have to move `getPesanans` out of the `useEffect` call in your component and decouple the mixed concerns like you did with `keranjang`...

```js
import { getProducts, getCategories, getPesanans } from "./api"

const Main = () => {
  const [dataProduct, setDataProduct] = useState([])
  const [dataCategories, setDataCategories] = useState([])
  const [categoriesId, setCategoriesId] = useState(1)
  const [listPesanan, setListPesanan] = useState([])

  const handleListCategories = (id) => {
    setCategoriesId(id)
  }

  const handleProdukClick = (produk) => {
    keranjang(produk).then(setListPesanan).catch(console.error)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getProducts(categoriesId).then(setDataProduct).catch(console.error)
    getCategories().then(setDataCategories).catch(console.error)
    getPesanans().then(setListPesanan).catch(console.error)
  }, [categoriesId]) // ✅ no infinite loop

  return (...)
}
```

**api**

Define a reusable `api` module so each component does not need to concern itself with `axios`, building URLs, or picking apart responses.

- ✅ Reusable functions separate concerns
- ✅ `.then(res => res.data)` allows caller to access data directly
- ✅ Errors are not swallowed
- ✅ `axios.create` makes [instance](https://axios-http.com/docs/instance) so you don't have to add `BASE_URL` to everything

```js
import axios from "axios"
import BASE_URL from "../utils/constata";

const client = axios.create({ baseURL: BASE_URL })

const getProducts = (categoriesId) =>
  client.get("/products?category.id=" + categoriesId).then(res => res.data)

const getCategories = () =>
  client.get("/categories").then(res => res.data)

const getPesanans = () =>
  client.get("/keranjangs").then(res => res.data)

export { getProducts, getCategories, getPesanans }
```

**homework**

- ✏️ Move `get`, `add`, and `increase` functions you wrote in `keranjang` to the `api` module.
- ✏️ Remove unnecessary `BASE_URL`
- ✏️ Rename them accordingly and add them to the `export` list
- ✏️ Any time you see `axios` spilling into your other components, refactor and move them to your `api` module
- ✏️ Consider using `transformRequest` and `transformResponse` in your [axios config](https://axios-http.com/docs/req_config) so you don't have to add `.then(res => res.data)` to *each* request
- ✏️ Consider decoupling `swal` and `keranjang`. `keranjang` can move to the `api` module and `swal` can be called from your component.

  ```js
  // api.js
  const keranjang = async (produk) => {
    const pesanan = await get(produk.id)
    if (pesanan.length === 0)
      return add(produk)
    else
      return increase(pesanan[0], produk)
  }
  ```

  ```js
  // component.js
  const Main = () => {
    // ...
    const handleProdukClick = (produk) => {
      keranjang(produk)
        .then(setListPesanan)
        .then(_ => swal({
          title: "Berhasil",
          text: "Masuk Keranjang " + produk.nama,
          icon: "success",
          button: "Oke",
        }))
        .catch(console.error)
    }
    // ...
  }
  ```
- ✏️ `util/keranjang` is now an empty module and can be removed

Comment: thanks for the advice, I follow your code but when I click, the screen become white